# SQL/PHP Multi-value Filtering (AND LIKE 'array[1]' AND LIKE 'array[2]')

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic, keyword

Question: How do I make SQL auto-adjust to array length and make an "AND LIKE ''" statement for each value of an array?

Basically I'm trying to make the following dynamic: (I'm using mySQL 5.6.17)

so the code would be

```
SELECT ... WHERE  .. AND AO LIKE '%$descr[0]%' AND AO LIKE '%$descr[1]%' AND AO LIKE '%$descr[2]%'
```

The above code would work fine, I've missed the irrelevant bits out.. The only issue is, I don't know how many array elements I will have, so I can't just create a load of AND AO LIKE for everything... Also, I don't know what they will be as they are user defined. I don't know how to many this dynamic to just make an' AND AO LIKE 'for each element in $descr. Please help.

Incase it isn't obvious,

AO is the column
$descr is the array of user-defined keywords of varying length.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I appreciate your input, but my issue is not that I have tried things and they don't work, it's simply that I don't know the term to use in SQL and no amount of google seems to be yielding the result for me, so I hoped somebody could understand what I'm trying to do and help with it

Comment: The issue is that we don't see your effort in your question.. Try adding what you have tried and where it's going wrong or what isn't working... We are here to help you if you have put some efoort in it, but not to write full code for you..

Comment: One of my biggest gripes with stackoverflow is how everyone on it expects you to ask questions as if you already know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing your $descr will come through as an array - would something like the below help you?

```
$descr = array(
    'hello',
    'world',
    'foo',
    'bar'
);

$sql[] = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME';

if(is_array($descr) and count($descr) > 0) {
    $sql[] = 'WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE \'%' . array_pop($descr) . '%\'';

    foreach($descr as $des) {
        $sql[] = 'AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE \'%' . $des . '$\'';
    }
}
echo implode(' ', $sql);
```

**Result:** SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%bar%' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%hello$' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%world$' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%foo$'

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I'm looking for Sephedo! I had overlooked the fact that the $sql is just a string... Rookie error right?

Comment: Its okay its easy to manipulate sql querys based on arrays however if you are looking for something a bit more stable there is plenter of SQL query builder classes which is what you should be searching for which will allow you to do some like $query = new Query(); $query->where('column', like', 'value')->where('column', 'like', 'value')->etc. and it will work this out for you.

Comment: This solution is highly vulnerable (SQL Injection). Never ever concatenate/build SQL queries without escaping user input! Use parameter/value binding or the driver's escape methods.

Comment: That is an assumption based on where $descr comes from... the question was about how to achieve this nothing about security or best practice could make the assumption this has already been done.